# Namespacing in socket.io when sending to a particular socket

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

When i namespace my app, i run into a problem i want to send data to a particular socket, here's the abbreviated version of the code I'm using:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(config.web.port);

var chat = io.of('space').on('connection', function (socket) {

  // This works:
  // Input: xhr-polling received data packet 5::/space:{"name":"test"}
  // Output: xhr-polling writing 5::/space:{"name":"test","args":[{"msg":"test"}]}
  socket.on('test', function(){
    socket.emit('test',{msg: "test"});
  });

  // This fails:
  // Input: xhr-polling received data packet 5::/space:{"name":"test2"}
  // Output: xhr-polling writing 5:::{"name":"test2","args":[{"msg":"test2"}]}      
  socket.on('test2',function(){
    io.sockets.socket(socket.id).emit('test2',{msg: "test2"});
  });
}
```

As you can see, the second one lacks the namespace part from the output. In the real app I'm picking the socket id from  a client manager so I'm using socket.id in this piece of code instead of client.getSocketId(), but the idea is the same as I'm just echoing to the origin client here.

How do i make the second method to use the correct namespace when outputting to the client?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After checking out [the source for `SocketNamespace`](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/blob/master/lib/namespace.js), it appears the syntax is `io.of('space').socket(id).emit(...`.

[**Edit** per Fuu's comment]

To find this, I checked the Socket.IO [GitHub repository](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io) and looked for a file that would have to do with namespaces--`namespace.js` seemed to fit the bill. The file wasn't very long, so I scanned it looking for methods on `SocketNamespace`'s prototype that looked like it might do what we wanted.

Since you call `io.sockets.socket` to find a socket on the global namespace, `SocketNamespace.prototype.socket` stuck out to me as being promising. Furthermore, it takes a parameter called `sid`, and the body of the method appears to be fetching a socket from a hash of sockets by this ID. A `Socket` is what we want (it holds the `emit` method), so my presumption was that this is the method to use in this case.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem! Could you be so kind and edit your answer to include the way you figured this out from the source of SocketNamespace? Reading through it I couldn't figure it out. I'd like to learn the details. :)

Comment: Hmm, I get the function of SocketNamespace.prototype.socket part, but how do you infer from that that one needs to replace of('namespace') for sockets in 'io.sockets.socket()'?

Comment: Because you use `io.of('space')` to return the namespace object up in your second line of code, so you can use it again here.